# ¿Cómo se puede agregar un tiempo (muerto) a una aplicación durante su ejecución?

Tags: java

Tengo un bucle "for" y necesito agregar un lapsus
 de un segundo por cada bucle recorrido

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 10000; i++) {
  //Función o algo que haga que se pare la aplicación en un segundo
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas esto? ¿Qué es lo que estás haciendo y qué necesitas conseguir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algo así como  `Thread.sleep(1000);` ?

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i <= 10000; i++)
{
  //Pausa de 1 segundo

  Thread.sleep(1000);

 // continúa el proceso

}
```

Creo que es mejor incluirle `try`

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
      //Pausa de 1 segundo

    try {  
      Thread.sleep(1000);

   } catch(InterruptedException ex) {

      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }

     // continúa el proceso

    }
```

Comment: oooo !! funcionó perfecto ! jaja gracias, el concepto es pausar la aplicación.

Comment: Mientras que esto responde funcionalmente la pregunta, sería mejor detenerse un momento a ver qué es lo que realmente se necesita lograr. Cuidado cuando utilizas este método puesto que en ciertos ambientes no es recomendado, por ejemplo en aplicaciones móviles o de escritorio.

Answer (score 0):

El `Thread.sleep()` es la herramienta base, pero también cabe considerar el uso de un **limitador de velocidad** ("rate limiter") como el [`RateLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) en la biblioteca [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki), que es igualmente fácil de usar pero resuelve muchos más problemas.  Por ejemplo, con el `RateLimiter` es fácil limitar la velocidad de una aplicación con multiples hilos de ejecución.